# Use token from local storage in HTTP request in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My Ionic 2 app has a login and it stores the auth token to the local storage. Then I want to use this token in my HTTP requests.

In my auth service I have the following method:

```
authToken() {
      return this.storage.get('auth_token').then((val) => {
         return val;
      });
    }
```

And then in my service that makes the HTTP request I have:

```
export class Rides {

    token: string;

    constructor(public http: Http, public authentification: Authentification) {
        this.authentification.authToken().then((val) => {
            this.token = val;
            console.log(this.token);
        });
    }

    getOpenRides() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Token token=' + this.token);
        return this.http.get('URL', { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

It logs the correct token in my Rides service constructor. But then when I use the token in the HTTP request my server says that token=undefined was sent.

What do I have to do different?

This is the page component where I call getOpenRides and where I want to display the result:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Rides } from '../../providers/rides';

/*
  Generated class for the Agenda page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-agenda',
  templateUrl: 'agenda.html',
  providers: [Rides]
})
export class AgendaPage {

    openRides: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public rides: Rides) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.openRides = this.rides.getOpenRides()
    .subscribe(response => { console.log(response.rides) });
  }
```

}

Comment: when and where are you calling the `getOpenRides` function?

Comment: I call it in a page component where I want to display the open rides. I added it to my question.

Comment: Hmm, and I assume you set the auth token in another component? If that is the case, the problem should lay in the `providers: [Rides]` in your components. Where-ever you declare providers in a component, means that it's a new instance of service, so it will not have access to properties that is set by another component and service. Try to add `providers: [Rides, AuthService]` in your ngModule instead, and remove the single providers from the components. This means that all components in that module uses the **same** service and have access to variables set from other components.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should lie in the fact that you are marking providers in your components, which means, when each component is instantiated, they are using a new clean instance of the service, where the token is undefined.

If you put the providers in your `NgModule` instead of components, it means that the service is the same for all components in that module. So when your `AgendaPage`-component is instantiated, it will have the same service as the one that was setting the token.

So remove providers from (all) your components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-agenda',
  templateUrl: 'agenda.html',
  // providers: [Rides] // remove!
})
```

and declare in your `NgModule` instead:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [ Rides, .... ], // add this!
  bootstrap: [ ... ]
})
```

Hope this helps! :)